# qt creator получения времени

Tags: c++, qt

Имею вот такой код, который по моему мнению, должен мне выводить время компьютера.

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDate>
#include <QTime>

int main(void) {

   QTextStream out(stdout);

   QDate dt2;
   dt2.setDate(QDateTime::currentDateTime());
   out << dt2.toString("yyyy/MM/dd") << endl;
}
```

к сожалению данный код не работает. где моя ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QDateTime dt2 = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
qDebug() << dt2.toString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Или как более короткий вариант:

```
qDebug()<<QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Добавлю, что приведенный код не скомпилируется, функция `QDate::setDate` принимает на вход `int year, int month, int day`, а вы пытаетесь передать объект класса `QDateTime`. Дата и время в Qt описывается классом `QDateTime`, так что если вам надо хранить и дату и время в одной сущности, рекомендую использовать именно его.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDate>
#include <QTime>

int main(void) {

   QTextStream out(stdout);

   QDate dt2 = QDate::currentDate();
   out << dt2.toString("yyyy/MM/dd");
}
```

На будущее: пишите подробнее вот это Ваше "код не работает". Необходимо уточнять: не компилируется; компилируется, но выводит не то что нужно, уточнить что выводит, а что хотите получить.